# How to get the prevously visited url inside of a react privite route component using reacat router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I want to do some logic if the user is coming back from stripe customer portal `"https://checkout.stripe.com/"`.

The issue is that I cannot find the object that contains such info that will confirm that a redirection happened from the aforementioned URL.

```
// React
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router';
// Redux
import { useAppSelector } from '../../redux-store/hooks';
import LoadingComponent from '../application/LoadingComponent';

interface Props {}

const AppPrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  // React Router
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  // Redux
  const currentUser = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.currentUser);
  const authenticating = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.authenticating);

  console.log('private route', currentUser);
  console.log('private route', authenticating);

  return authenticating
    ? <LoadingComponent action={'Authenticating'} />
    : currentUser?.authenticated
      ? <Outlet />
      : <Navigate to='/' />;
};

export default AppPrivateRoute;
```

Comment: why not have a route to handle this? u can update the success_url(u need to add this when creating checkout) to redirect for a specific route?
ie: yourdomain.com/order/confirm
sucess_url docs:  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works

Comment: you are right but I don't want to mess with the router since it there already a complex abstraction on this route. and want to just extract it since the the initial redirect happens from the app to begin with.

Comment: where is the complexity? i cannot understand this requirement!, could u explain the code that u have shared does not seems to be complex at all

Comment: would be good if u can create a gist and explain how do u need to handle the redirection from the stripe checkout page

Comment: @Afzal the complexity is In the nested component that has Security rules… still we are getting out of the point .. is react router capable of remebering the path that we are coming from .. (prev path)

Comment: from what i know it does not, but if u still want to retain this and not have a different route how about u have a query param for the same, and u can check on your component if this query param exists u can treat it as checkout page (not that somehow u need to validate this on the server, i suggest have some kind of id in the query param)

Comment: @Afzal thanks for the info, the issue is tbh that the Customer portal is not standalone mode friendly and it is shrinking my apps page due to the fact that it renders  in some sort of external browser … and the only way to fix the page as for now is to flip the screen … this why I am trying to for example to refresh the page after returning.

Comment: Are you asking for [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)?

Comment: @DrewReese hi, drew, I tried it before but it was empty.

Comment: Then wherever the user is getting navigated from will need to pass this information along manually (*request payload, query parameter, etc.*) for your app to pick it up.